# Using cordova plugins in InAppBrowser

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

Is it possible to use cordova plugins in a site in InAppBrowser? And when how? 
The deviceready event is never fired in the InAppBrowser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it isn't possible to use Cordova plugins within a InAppBrowser. You are only limited to to the [addEventListeners](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#addeventlistener) there are. And Cordova is not loaded within the InAppBrowser.

You can ofcourse [inject Javascript](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#executescript), but that is also different than running a complete Cordova within the InAppBrowser.