# Cordova Plugin inappbrowser : How use Cordova in Cordova Webview?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

1. I installed the plugin: In App Browser
   https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser

Documentation is here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

2. Dynamically, I created an HTML page in this directory: this.file.dataDirectory
3. I try to load this page on the webview like this:

**IMPORT**

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser/ngx';
```

**CONSTRUCTOR**

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) {}
```

**MY CODE**

```
const browser = this.iab.create( this.webview.convertFileSrc( this.file.dataDirectory + 'jojo/index.html' ) );
```

Everything is ok and there aren't problems.
My page jojo/index.html can load.

**The page is load in the Cordova WebView**

If I don't mistake, 
because I don't set the "target" value (the value is still "_self")
my page jojo/index.html is load in the Cordova WebView. Right ?

Reference:

[image]

So ... on my page, I want to use ionic functions (or cordova functions).

How can I do that ?

PS: I already check this topic: [Using cordova plugins in InAppBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30622959/using-cordova-plugins-in-inappbrowser) and it's a different case. Their target are "_blank", so them pages are open in the InAppBrowser.

**My config**

This is my configuration:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 11 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/jojo/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
   NodeJS            : v11.10.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : macOS Mojave
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access any Cordova functions directly from an InAppBrowser window. Instead, you need to communicate between the InAppBrowser and the Cordova WebView using the (only?) method available, the `message` event handler.

[Check out this article](https://www.andreszsogon.com/how-to-close-inappbrowser-window-in-cordova-by-itself/) on how to implement the `message` event handler with an InAppBrowser window. In the example, you send a *close* message from the IAB to the WebView to instruct Cordova to close the IAB, but you can change that and send whatever messages you want, to perform different actions in the WebView side.

This is the sample code from the **WebView** side:

```js
function openInAppBrowser() {
    // Open URL
    var open_url = 'http://www.sampleurl.com/sample.htm';
    inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(open_url, '_blank', 'clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,location=yes,hardwareback=no,zoom=no');
    // Add event listener to close the InAppBrowser
    inAppBrowserRef.addEventListener('message', messageCallBack);
};

function messageCallBack(params) {
    // Close the InAppBrowser if we received the proper message
    if(params.data.action == 'close') {
        inAppBrowserRef.close();
    }
};
```

Refer to the article for the JS code in the **InAppBrowser** side, and modify it to suit your needs.

**Notice you must use the 3.1.0-dev version of the inappbrowser plugin for this event handler to work**.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. But How to access to my page jojo/index.html ? Indeed, I don't want to load a external url like your example "http://www.sampleurl.com/sample.html" I want to load a internal url (I want create pages inside the application. How can I do that ?). It's too strange : create a Cordova Webview and can't use cordova functions...

Comment: how can I do that with "_blank" parameter ? var open_url = this.webview.convertFileSrc( this.file.dataDirectory + 'jojo/index.html' ); inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(open_url, '_blank', 'clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,location=yes,hardwareback=no,zoom=no');

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with loading internal pages to the InAppBrowser, and personally I think the IAB hasn't been created for that, so it probably cannot do it.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. So ok, your are true ! I will not use InAppBrowser. So how can use Cordova functionnality in the Cordova WebView. I can load my page jojo/index.html like this: window.location.href = this.webview.convertFileSrc( this.file.dataDirectory + 'jojo/index.html' ); It's Works ! But now I want to use cordova functions (or ionic functions). How can I do that ? Do you have a idea ?